# Softly spin down harddisk on Linux

Tags: linux, hard-drive, power-management

I've got an external USB-C harddisk connected to my computer. If, after 'ejecting' it, pull the plug, it spins down with a clanky noise. So it does, if I power it off by the disk utility (eg Gnome disks) or by issuing

```
sudo hdparm -y /dev/sdb
```

However, if I send the computer to standby, the harddisk spins down gently, without any aggressive noise at all. I can disconnect it then, and wake up the computer again.

How to achieve this smooth spindown by software means?

Comment: After "ejecting" (*unmounting* in Linux parlance) the disk, how long did you wait before unplugging it? (Windows takes as long as half a minute to display or eject an external HDD.)

Comment: What happens if you use `hdparm -S` to put the drive in standby mode, or `hdparm -S <number>` to set a spindown time? See `man hdparm` for details.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik there is a notification if the disk is ready to unplug. So it is completely unmounted by then.

Comment: `hdparm -S` triggers the same clanky hard shutdown for this drive

Comment: As of today, I've still have this harddisk in use, and still the computer manages to spin it down silently (when going to standby) but not if switching of by software or unplugging. Interesting. Maybe the Laptops BIOS (Thinkpad T480s) knows better how to put disks to sleep? Or is it the Linux kernel, but a different mechanism, if entering standby? That's still the question...